# Typescript: How to display maximum value from database

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am working in Ionic and I'm trying to make a for loop to display maximum value from data in database.

I am currently have some data in database. The data is something like this:

```
[{
    "name": "HAREEZ HAKIMI",
    "gender": "M",
    "dob": "1980-12-15",
    "age": 37,
},
{
    "name": "kids new name",
    "gender": "F",
    "dob": "2015-09-28",
    "age": 2,
},
{
    "name": "SRIDHAR",
    "gender": "M",
    "dob": "1987-12-15",
    "age": 30,
}]
```

I need to display data that will show the highest age. For this case, the expected output would be:

```
Name:HAREEZ HAKIMI
Gender:M
Birth Date:1980-12-15
Age: 37
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <ion-grid *ngFor="let jobseeker of kidList">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12 class="header-list">Kids</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Name: {{jobseeker.name}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Gender: {{jobseeker.gender}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Birth Date: {{jobseeker.dob}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Age: {{jobseeker.age}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

Currently my typescript code is like this:

```
for (let kids of this.kidList) {
      if (kids.age > maxAge) {
        maxAge = kids.age;
      }
    }
    return maxAge;
```

For now, the browser display all data that consist in the database. Can anybody show me on how to display the highest age only? Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let oldest = {};

for (let kids of this.kidList) {
      if (kids.age > oldest.age) {
        oldest = kids;
      }
    }
```

Then in your markup you could try this:

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 class="header-list">Kids</ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Name: {{oldest.name}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Gender: {{oldest.gender}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Birth Date: {{oldest.dob}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Age: {{oldest.age}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. There could be many different ways, but this is just a matter of having a variable that contains a single kid entry with highest age value (namely `oldestkid` for the sake of this conversation),

and instead of using `*ngFor`, just print out `oldestKid` (you may need to check if `oldestKid` is set to some value or not in case `kidList` is empty)

If you still want to use `*ngFor`, then consider using ([pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let arr = [
                {
                    "name": "HAREEZ HAKIMI",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "dob": "1980-12-15",
                    "age": 37,
                },
                {
                    "name": "kids new name",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "dob": "2015-09-28",
                    "age": 2,
                },
                {
                    "name": "SRIDHAR",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "dob": "1987-12-15",
                    "age": 30,
                }
            ];

            function getMax(arr, prop) {
                let max;
                for (let i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++) {
                    if (!max || parseInt(arr[i][prop]) > parseInt(max[prop]))
                        max = arr[i];
                }
                return max;
            }
        this.jobseeker = getMax(arr, "age");
        console.log(this.jobseeker);
```

in html

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12 class="header-list">Kids</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Name: {{jobseeker.name}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Gender: {{jobseeker.gender}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Birth Date: {{jobseeker.dob}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 class="item-list">Age: {{jobseeker.age}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: i have try this code but nothing appear on the screen

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to it. I think you need to learn the basics of JavaScript

Angular markup

```
 <ion-grid *ngFor="let jobseeker of kidsSortedByAge.slice(0, 1)">
```

JavaScript

```
class {
  get kidsSortedByAge() {
    return this.kidList.slice().sort((x, y) => y.age - x.age);
  } 
}
```